# Why won't the fluid go in?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I made a cylinder and made into a cup, but for some reason the fluid I'm trying to put in it wont go in the cup. :/ [image]

Comment: Maybe you need to turn it right side up? Usually works for me in real life. ;-) Or maybe there's something else going on. Can you post the .blend? [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: have you checked normals direction, hidden faces, removed doubles, etc? and which volume initialization setting are you using?